# Walk beside the trees or under the trees

Tags: sentence-usage

Which sentence is correct? I am walking beside the trees or I am walking under the tree?

Comment: We need more context for this.  Why do you think either question might have a mistake. Where do these sentences come from. How to you intend to use them. Please have a look at the [tour] and the [help] to see how to ask better questions.

Comment: They are both correct, they just mean two different things

Comment: Where are you in relation to the tree(s)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
She is walking **beside** the trees.

[image]
They are walking **under** the trees.